# Initializing a variable in the constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, std, glfw

I'm trying to set up a object with an vector as a member field. I set up the constructor, and as far as I'm aware it does initialize this member variable, but I am getting an error when I try to access the vector unless I initialize it within the function calls of the object. I'm getting a warning saying

`C26495: Variable 'Engy::Graphics::Shape2D::m_vertices' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).`

The thing is, I did initialize it in my constructor. Is there anything vital I'm missing? Here's my code:

**Class declaration (Header File)**

```
class Shape2D:Object
        {
            protected:
                std::vector<Vector> *m_vertices;
                int type = GL_QUADS;
            public:
                Shape2D(std::vector<Vector> vertices);
                Shape2D();
                void draw();
                void setVector(int index, Vector value);
                Vector getVector(int index);
                void translate(double x, double y);
                void createVector(int i, double x, double y);
                void createVector(double x, double y);
                void addVector(Vector value);
        };
```

**Method declaration (.cpp file)**

```
Shape2D::Shape2D(std::vector<Vector> vertices)
{
    std::vector<Vector> m_vertices = vertices;
}
Shape2D::Shape2D()
{
    std::vector<Vector> *m_vertices = new std::vector<Vector>;
}

void Shape2D::setVector(int index, Vector value)
{
    //THIS PART RIGHT HERE IS WHAT I HAVE TO DO TO MAKE IT NOT CRASH, BUT I DONT WANT TO HAVE TO PUT THIS EVERYWHERE
    if (!m_vertices)
    {
        m_vertices = new std::vector<Vector>;
    }
    if (m_vertices->size() < index)
    {
        m_vertices->assign(index - m_vertices->size(), NULL);       
    }
    m_vertices->at(index) = value;
}
```

**Object Creation**

```
    //Rectangle is a subclass of Shape2D which calls the default constructor of Shape2D then runs calls to add the constructor inputs in (Let me know if you would like to see that code)
    Rectangle r(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5);
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: Why is the member variable `m_vertices` a pointer?  Why not just a `std::vector`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but please read your book/tutorial/coursework more closely, or get better ones if they haven't explained clearly how to initialise members.

Comment: Yeah I'm self-taught c++, I'm coming from java and c# so this is all new to me haha

Comment: @LincolnDoney: For learning C++ from Java, here's a tip: _Never_ use `new`, and almost never use `T*` pointers.

Answer (score 5):

The line

```
std::vector<Vector> m_vertices = vertices;
```

does not initialize the member variable. It initializes a function local variable of the same name. The function local variables hides/shadows the member variable.

The best practice is to initialize members using the [*member-initialization-list*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.base.init#nt:mem-initializer-list) syntax.

```
Shape2D::Shape2D(std::vector<Vector> vertices) : m_vertices(vertices)
{
}
```

That will require one change to your class. You will need to change `m_vertices` to a vector object instead of pointer.

```
std::vector<Vector> m_vertices;
```

That's a good practice anyway.

Comment: I'm suggesting OP go even further than that.

Answer (score 2):

1. You're defining and initializing a local variable named `m_vertices` in your constructor, not your class' member variable.
2. You shouldn't use a pointer, nor `new`, nor `delete` - the member vector is "owned" by the class instance.

... and other answers suggest a class design based on these corrections (e.g. @RSahu's answer). However - there's a problem, still. It doesn't make sense to me that you would want, on the one hand, to be able to have complete editing control over a shape's vertices, and on the other hand, to keep the vertex vector protected. Also, shapes are not expected to grow, and grow, and grow. So I would suggest something else entirely:

```
class Shape2D : Object {
public:
    using vertex_type = Vector;
    using vertices_type = std::vector<vertex_type>;
protected:
    const vertices_type m_vertices;
public:
    Shape2D() = delete;
    Shape2D(vertices_type vertices) : m_vertices(std::move(vertices)) { }
    Shape2D(const Shape2D& shape) = default;
    Shape2D(Shape2D&& shape) = default;

    // other methods here, but -  no methods for editing vertices!
}
```

Now, a shape is (essentially) immutable as far as its vertices are concerned. Want to change a shape? Create a new shape object.

Alternatively, if you *must* have edit access to the vertices (which I doubt) - consider exposing `m_vertices` via an accessor method, either in `Shape2D` or in a subclass, say, `EditableShaped2D`:

```
vertices_type& EditableShape2D::vertices() { return m_vertices; }
```

and not all of the trouble you've gone to.

Comment: Interesting POV. Whether a `Shape` is immutable is a design choice. In most cases, you would like to be able edit an object in place instead of constructing a new one.

Comment: @RSahu: Added a suggestion about that which would not necessitate adding all those add/remove/change methods.

Comment: This is probably the smartest move.. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Is it a good move to still keep the draw() method and other methods which use the vectors but don't mutate them?

Comment: @LincolnDoney: Oh, sure, I didn't mean remove all the methods, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

In this constructor:

```
Shape2D::Shape2D()
{
    std::vector<Vector> *m_vertices = new std::vector<Vector>;
}
```

you are declaring a *separate* variable `m_vertices`, so the member variable never gets initialized.

Instead, you should simply do:

```
Shape2D::Shape2D()
{
   m_vertices = new std::vector<Vector>;
}
```

However, you should use member initializer lists to initialize members, like this:

```
Shape2D::Shape2D() : m_vertices {new std::vector<Vector>} {}
```

Note that your single constructor argument will also need to be fixed. This will result in an error, since the types won't match. You can fix this by allocating memory there as well.

That being said, I would suggest rethinking the design, to see if you can avoid doing manual memory management at all. e.g. you have not defined a destructor, so you will leak memory. Also, you would need to implement the copy-constructor, etc, yourself.

Comment: Member initialization should be performed in an initialization list when possible, rather than in the constructor body. So, @RSahu's suggestion is the better one.

Answer (score 1):

In the default constructor:

```
Shape2D::Shape2D()
{
    std::vector<Vector> *m_vertices = new std::vector<Vector>;
}
```

you define a brand new variable with the name `m_vertices` that is distinct and independent from the `Shape2D` member variable with the same name. This local variable *shadow* the member variable.

You can use a member initializer list to solve that problem:

```
Shape2D::Shape2D()
    : m_vertices{ new std::vector<Vector> }
{
}
```

You have a similar problem in the other constructor as well, but also a different one: The argument is not a pointer, and you can't make `m_vertices` point to that argument. The solution to this is to not use a pointer at all for the vector. You almost never need a pointer to a container.

So actually the solution for *both* problems is just to declare `m_vertices` in the class as a plain object, not a pointer:

```
class Shape2D
{
    std::vector<Vector> m_vertices;  // Not a pointer
    ...
};
```